# Activity.findViewById() returns null in Espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso

In an Espresso test, I want to get reference to my `ViewPager` so I can attach an `IdlingResource` to it. But `findViewById` returns `null`, even though I confirm just before that the `ViewPager` is displayed.

```
// Passes
onView(withId(R.id.viewPager)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
Activity activity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
assertNotNull(activity);
// Fails
assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.viewPager));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you switch activities in your test?

Comment: No. I only use the activity created in the rule. The viewpager is in a dialog fragment spawned in the activity, though, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide not that much information. But lets work with what we have.

I assume the `Activity` has been started successfully and the `DialogFragment` (that contains the `ViewPager`) is displayed too:

The first line of your posted code `onView(withId(R.id.viewPager)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` does pass, because Espresso searches trough all views that have been added to the current window. And the dialog is somewhere in the window's layout hierarchy.

But `assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.viewPager));` does fail, because the `ViewPager` is not in the content view of the `Activity` but in the `FragmentDialog`.

You can verify view hierarchy with the help of the [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html). Compare the hierarchy with and without the dialog.

Why do you want to add an `IdlingResource` to the `ViewPager`?

Comment: Oh, ffs. You are absolutely right. I've been working too hard. I wanted the IdlingResource because I was attempting to write a test involving the swiping ability of ViewPager, but Espresso does not wait for the swiping to complete which was causing my test to fail. It passes just fine now that I'm looking for it in the fragment, where it is, instead of the activity.